# How to suggest that implantation of interface has some specified data member?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

i want the classes implementing myInterface should have some particular data members. 
But if i specify them in interface they become final. So is there any way by declaring a method in interface i suggest them to make a particular datamember?

```
public interface myInterface{
    boolean idNameSafe();
    //add something that they make id and name datamember in their class
} 

public class myClass implements myInterface{
    //should have long id
    //should have string name
    //myClass's datamember

    @Override
    public boolean idNameSafe(){
        //checks the id and name and does something on it
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces don't care about implementation, so no.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to define your interface to have a member function that retrieves your suggested value than forcing the implementer to have that variable?

Comment: Add a getter, that way the implementor will need to implement the getter somehow.

Comment: @zero298 but then that member become final if i write them in interface. I dont want it to be final

Comment: @LakshyaSharma when I say "member", I mean member function.

Comment: okay i got it now thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to require an interface's children to create fields.  To hint at it, you could always add some more methods to the interface requiring child classes to return an `id` and `name`, and then validate them within the interface using a default method.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    default boolean idNameSafe() {
        // Perform your check(s) here using getId() and getName()
    }

    int getId();

    String getName();
}
```